# Splitting Up Lists of Lists by Length in Python

Tags: python, list

Given the following problem, what is the most efficient (or reasonably efficient) way to do this in Python:

**Problem.**  Given a list of lists,

```
L = [list_0, list_1, list_2, list_3, ..., list_n]
```

where len(list_i) <= 3, let's say, for each list inside of L.  How can we split up L into L_1, L_2, L_3, where L_1 has only length 1 lists, L_2 has only length 2 lists, and L_3 has only length 3 lists?

**Potential Solutions.**  Here's the best I could do; I've also included a sample set here as well.  It runs in around 8.6 seconds on my PC.

```
import time

# These 4 lines make a large sample list-of-list to test on.
asc_sample0 = [[i] for i in range(500)]
asc_sample1 = [[i,j] for i in range(500) for j in range(20)]
asc_sample2 = [[i,j,k] for i in range(20) for j in range(10) for k in range(20)]
asc_sample = asc_sample0 + asc_sample1 + asc_sample2

start = time.clock()
cells0 = [i for i in asc if len(i) == 1]
cells1 = [i for i in asc if len(i) == 2]
cells2 = [i for i in asc if len(i) == 3]
print time.clock() - start
```

I also attempted to "pop" elements off and append to lists cells0, etc., but this took significantly longer.  I also attempted to append and then remove that element so I could get through in one loop which worked okay when there were, say, 10^10 lists of size 1, but only a few of size 2 and 3, but, in general, it was not efficient.

I'd mostly appreciate some neat ideas.  I know that one of the answers will most likely be "Write this in C", but for now I'd just like to look at Python solutions for this.

Comment: What's the point of `L_3`? You just said `len(list_i) <= 2` for all lists in L.

Comment: You could probably get a significant speedup by sorting the list and then using `itertools.groupby`

Comment: @slider Sorry; I meant that to be a 3.  It's a bit confusing because length 1 lists stand for "0-cells", length 1 lists stand for "1-cells", etc., so I get mixed up a bunch.  Edited to reflect this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely one of the best because it runs in parallel.  Another thing that you should look at though is the `itertools.groupby` and the built-in `filter` method.

Comment: The itertools.groupby looks good; I'll try this out.  For the filter method, the doc for 2.7.x says that this is equivalent to the list comprehension above, unless I'm thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: The `filter` method creates a *generator* in python 3.x which a number of advantages over the list comprehension.

Comment: If you want to use groupby you need to sort by length first

Comment: As gnibbler points out, I think groupby needs a sorted list first.  And sorting these seem to take a bunch of time (at least on my PC, on Python 2.7.x).  Maybe there's a way around the sorting?

Comment: Look up **count sort**

Comment: Also, please note that I am only trying to point @james in a direction so that he can come to his own conclusions.  I'm not claiming that this is perfect answer.

Comment: It still runs a bit lower than the original for very, very large lists, even using some of the numpy implementations of count sort --- at least for me.  I'm glad to have learned about count sort, though, since this kind of problem comes up for me a lot and I never knew there was a sort for that kind of thing!

Comment: If you like count sort, look up radix sort.

Comment: Radix sort looks sweet, but I have no idea what I'd use it for!

Answer (score 2):

An old fashioned solution might work better here:

```
cells0, cells1, cells2 = [], [], []

for lst in asc_sample:
    n = len(lst)
    if n == 1:
        cells0.append(lst)
    elif n == 2:
        cells1.append(lst)
    else:
        cells2.append(lst)
```

Comment: Exactly. One iteration instead of three.

Comment: I used `cells_by_length = collections.defaultdict(list)` to shorten the code for the inner loop to `for sublist in asc_sample: cells_by_length[len(sublist)].append(sublist)` but it's the same idea.

Comment: This runs slower than the original on my computer!

Comment: I thought that this might have been slower because of the "append" part, but I was wrong --- this is a bit faster than my method.  Nice!

Comment: After a little more testing on a few more randomly generated lists-of-lists, this seems to either be slightly better or slightly worse than the original one.  Is there maybe some lag created by the appending on very, very long lists?  It's strange, because I'd expect the original to have the same problems.

Comment: Lists in python have an *amortized* growth (their real size is always a power of 2) so you will see it slow down whenever the size of a list has to grow past a power of 2 because the system is reallocating it.  Whereas list comprehensions run in parallel so the system can predict how much memory it will need in advance.

Comment: Ha, that's strange --- that may be the problem here.  The lengths of the lists that make the do worse // do better cutoff seem to hover above // below the 2^n [for large n] limit.  There are a few exceptions, but that might explain what's happenin'.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = dict()

for lst in L:
    result.setdefault(len(lst), []).append(lst)

print result
```

**Output**

```
{
 1: [[0], [1], [2], [3]],
 2: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]],
 3: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2]]
}
```

Comment: This runs a bit slower than the rest, but not by much!  I didn't know about setdefault, though, which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing a list/tuple should be faster than doing key lookups. This is about 30% faster than the version given in the question

```
cells = [],[],[],[]     # first list here isn't used, but it's handy for the second version
for i in asc:
    cells[len(i)].append(i)
```

Slightly faster again by extracting the append methods (On larger lists this is almost twice as fast as the OP)

```
cells = [],[],[],[]
appends = [x.append for x in cells]
for i in asc:
    appends[len(i)](i)
```

Comment: For me, the first seems to run a bit slower on very, very large lists, but the second is a little faster than the original.  The second one is also neat because I had no idea you could do things like that --- or, at least, I don't think I've seen things like that before.